# Generating about thousand or more controls with ExtJS

Tags: extjs4

We have decided to use ExtJS for one of our large application's web-remake and we will have to generate screens/forms where we will have to render about thousand or more controls either in complete editable grid of in forms.

So may I know what is the best approach in doing so?

I have tried generating about thousand controls and it takes about more than 6 seconds on client-side and that too is going to be dependent on Client configuration about which I am positive that it will be at-least dual-core system most of the time.

But more than 6 seconds on localhost is like 10 seconds over the Internet so I am worried, I still have a choice of mixing normal html form/controls when there is high load but then it will miss the ExtJS touch (combo/number controls etc.), so any help or if you had similar experience do share.

Will XTemplate be faster in above case? I am still new to ExtJS so do share best practices if you know/used.

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw to me, will the user fill out 1000 controls before saving each time?

Comment: Not really, that could possibly a editable grid where all controls are open for editing w/o need to click on them to edit.

Basically grid will be filled with existing data entry over period of time.

Comment: Try to look at cellediting plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is not to do it this way. Creating thousands of controls will need huge amounts of memory, no matter how you do it. As you noticed, this makes an application extremely slow.

The solution is to keep the elements on the server and use some form of paging to create only the elements that the user can actually see.

Paging can be explicit ("Load next 10 rows") or implicit by firing an event when the scrollbar hits the right/bottom end and loading more rows.

Usually, you can even hide this from users. Always load a whole row (hiding elements in the same row which aren't visible because the browser window is too narrow usually doesn't help much).

On the server, you will know how many rows you have. Load the first 20 rows and display them. Find the height of the rows (ideally, they should be all the same height) and create an empty DIV below the 20 rows which expands the scrolled view. This makes it **appear** as if all the rows are there (user sees correct scrollbar which doesn't jump while scrolling).

As soon as that empty div comes into view, load more rows and shrink it.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron and we have to come up with some similar mechanism as a solution on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used ExtJs for a long time but IIRC, the lists and tables all offer lazy loading via data sources. If you want to make individual cells editable, install a click listener on the whole table and then inside the listener, locate the cell and replace it with an inline editor.